# Is a diagonalizable matrix also injective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

This question seems to be very basic, but I couldn't find the answer on SE.

I want to know if a diagonalizable matrix $A$, i.e. $A = SDS^{-1}$, is also an injective matrix, i.e. $Av = 0$ if and only if $v = 0$ or also $\ker A = \{ 0 \}$.

I believe it can be simply proven by

1. "a composition of injective functions is also injective" and
2. "$S, S^{-1}$ are injective because they are invertible and $D$ is injective because it is diagonal",

but I want to know if I am correct.

I'm not sure about the injectiveness of $D$. If this is the dealbreaker, what are criteria for the injectiveness of $D$ proceeding from the properties of $A$?

I am asking because this would imply, that the only fixed point of a dynamical system
$ \dot{\vec{x}} = A \vec{x}$ with a diagonalizable matrix $A$ would be only $\vec x = 0$.

Comment: If one of the eigenvalues are 0, D is not invertible and not injective.

Comment: The  zero matrix $D=0$ is clearly diagonal, so diagonalisable. What about the kernel of the zero matrix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, (the linear transformations given by) diagonal matrices are not injective in general, since a diagonal matrix can have zero entries on the diagonal (and a diagonalizable matrix can have $0$ as an eigenvalue). In fact, being diagonal or diagonalizable is irrelevant when it comes to being injective.

A square matrix describes an injective map exactly when $0$ is not an eigenvalue, or, equivalently, exactly when the determinant is nonzero. I don't think there is any simpler criterion.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to verify that a diagonal matrix is injective if and only if all diagonal entries are nonzero.

Your argument does show that $D$ is injective if and only if $A$ is injective. In general, a matrix $A$ is injective if and only if $\det A\neq0$, or equivalently if and only if $Av=0\ \Rightarrow\ v=0$.